# Why can't we convert flat columns of awkward1 arrays `to_parquet`?

Tags: parquet, awkward-array

A follow up from this question; [Best way to save a dict of awkward1 arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851761/best-way-to-save-a-dict-of-awkward1-arrays/66854439#66854439)

To save multiple columns of nested awkward1 arrays (with varying length);

```py
import awkward1 as ak
dog = ak.from_iter([[1, 2], [5]])
cat = ak.from_iter([[4]])
pets = ak.zip({"dog": dog[np.newaxis], "cat": cat[np.newaxis]}, depth_limit=1)

ak.to_parquet(pets, "pets.parquet")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for flat lists;

```py
import awkward1 as ak
dog = ak.from_iter([1, 2, 5])
cat = ak.from_iter([4])
pets = ak.zip({"dog": dog[np.newaxis], "cat": cat[np.newaxis]}, depth_limit=1)

ak.to_parquet(pets, "pets.parquet")
```

creates the error;

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7f3a7fefb261> in <module>
      3 cat = ak.from_iter([3])
      4 pets = ak.zip({"dog": dog[np.newaxis], "cat": cat[np.newaxis]}, depth_limit=1)
----> 5 ak.to_parquet(pets, "pets.parquet")

~/Programs/anaconda3/envs/tree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/operations/convert.py in to_parquet(array, where, explode_records, list_to32, string_to32, bytestring_to32, **options)
   2983     layout = to_layout(array, allow_record=False, allow_other=False)
   2984     iterator = batch_iterator(layout)
-> 2985     first = next(iterator)
   2986
   2987     if "schema" not in options:

~/Programs/anaconda3/envs/tree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/operations/convert.py in batch_iterator(layout)
   2978                 )
   2979             yield pyarrow.RecordBatch.from_arrays(
-> 2980                 pa_arrays, schema=pyarrow.schema(pa_fields)
   2981             )
   2982

~/Programs/anaconda3/envs/tree/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.RecordBatch.from_arrays()

TypeError: object of type 'pyarrow.lib.Tensor' has no len()
```

What is the reason for encountering this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found is a bug, and now it is fixed: https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/pull/799

What's happening here is that pyarrow can't write `pyarrow.lib.Tensor` (regular-length lists, such as the one you created with `np.newaxis`) to Parquet files. Parquet files don't have a concept of "regular-length list," so that makes sense. But rather than converting it, pyarrow hits an unhandled case, in which it fails to find the length of that `pyarrow.lib.Tensor`. (It's a little odd that `pyarrow.lib.Tensor` doesn't have a `__len__` method, but that's another thing.)

Anyway, with version 1.2.0 of Awkward Array, we'll simply convert regular-length lists into (in principle) variable-length lists when writing to Parquet, since the format doesn't have that type. According to the schedule, version 1.2.0 will be released tomorrow. (This bug-fix is likely the last prerelease.)

Comment: Wow, that was so fast. Thanks.